# Unity On-screen Button doesn't seem to hold down on touch screens

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, user-interface, mobile, game-development

I am using the New Input System and the unity On-screen button scripts provided in it.

My game has 4 buttons; Fire right, Fire left, Move left, Move right.
I have mapped the buttons using the On-screen button scripts to O (to fire left), P (to fire right), left arrow, right arrow. which is what is used when you play on PC.

The mapped controls for movement and UI are the default ones with the New Input System.

These on-screen buttons work fine when in Unity editor. The fire buttons tap, and the move buttons can be held down.

When I play the game on mobile, the fire buttons work as expected, but the move buttons don't.

Sometimes the character may move for a under a second  at the start of holding them down but don't work continuously as I'm holding down the button (as they do in the unity editor).

Can anyone suggest what is happening? or any other info needed?

```
void FixedUpdate()
{

    Vector3 targetVelocity = new Vector2(horizontalMove * speed, m_Rigidbody2D.velocity.y);

    m_Rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector3.SmoothDamp(m_Rigidbody2D.velocity, targetVelocity, ref m_Velocity, m_MovementSmoothing);
}

public void Move(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
{
    horizontalMove = context.ReadValue<Vector2>().x;
}
```

Comment: It’s likely you’ll need to post the code you’re using for the on-screen buttons and whatever accepts their input.

Comment: @SvenViking Thanks for responding. Added my player movement code to the main desc. The Button Code is using unity's own OnScreenButton script that is standard in The New Input System.

Comment: Afraid I’m not sure of the answer here but hopefully someone else will know something.

Comment: Only thing I can think to suggest is to check your Input System package is up to date.

Comment: Yeah, it is. Thanks for taking a look though!